# simple search results not including body content

Tags: simple-search

I am using the simple search by Expression Engine and the searches are fine, but they are just returning title results and not searching the body content. I have the excerpt search in the channel properties set to the right channel field in the channel preferences, but I am not sure if there is anything else I need to do.  Below is my search code and my search results code.

**SEARCH CODE**

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="blog|documents|static|overview|company|products|media|services|support|solutions" result_page="search/results"}
          <div class="icon"><img src="{site_url}assets/img/search.png" border="0"></div>
          <input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" placeholder="Search Site">
        {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

**SEARCH RESULTS CODE**

```
{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}
            {if count == 1}<ul>{/if}
              <li>
                <strong><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></strong>
                <p>{auto_path}</p>
              </li>
            {if count > 0 && count == total_results}</ul>{/if}

        {/exp:search:search_results}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `search_in="everywhere"` to your search form to search in the titles and entries.
The default is `titles`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `{auto_path}` where your  `{excerpt}` should be.

Comment: That is actually on purpose.  I am just showing the path to the url and not an excerpt of what is there.  The problem I am having is that my results don't include entries that have the keywords in the body content.  So it is actually the entries that are not showing up in the list that are the problem, and not the formatting of the results.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I'll post another answer.